# How to pass member of structure/union array into function

Tags: c++, c++17

For example, I want to display value of only one member of structure/union array, so I want to pass it as argument into a function that will display only that one member and will also display any other single member that I pass as argument.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

union ThreeTypes
{
    char letter;
    int whole;
    double real;
};

void showArr(ThreeTypes[], int); // ?? What parameters to pass?

int main()
{
    const int SIZE = 50;
    ThreeTypes arr[SIZE];
    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
        arr[i].real = 2.37;

    showArr(arr, SIZE, ??? ); // what argument to pass to display member?

    return 0;
}
void showArr(ThreeTypes arr[],int size,???) // also, what parameters??
{
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        cout << arr[i].?? << endl; // member from argument????
}
```

Answer (score 6):

One option would be a templated [pointer-to-member type](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/pointer#Pointers_to_members).  These are usually used with `class` or `struct` types, but are also valid with a `union` type.  A pointer-to-member type is declared like `MemberType ClassType::*pointer_name`, and the name of such a pointer can be used to the right of the `.*` or `->*` operator.

```
template <typename T>
void showArr(const ThreeTypes arr[], int size, T ThreeTypes::*ptr)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
        std::cout << (arr[i].*ptr) << std::endl;
}
```

And you create a pointer-to-member value with the syntax `&ClassType::member_name`:

```
int main()
{
    const int SIZE = 50;
    ThreeTypes arr[SIZE];
    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
        arr[i].real = 2.37;

    showArr(arr, SIZE, &ThreeTypes::real);
}
```

---

Another more general option would be to take a callable functor:

```
template <typename F>
void showArr(const ThreeTypes arr[], int size, const F& func)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
        std::cout << func(arr[i]) << std::endl;
}
```

You can create a functor to access a member using a lambda or [`std::mem_fn`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/mem_fn):

```
void print_reals_twice(const ThreeTypes arr[], int size)
{
    showArr(arr, size, [](const ThreeTypes& u) { return u.real; });
    // Same effects:
    showArr(arr, size, std::mem_fn(&ThreeTypes::real));
}
```

But defining `showArr` this way also lets you pass a functor that does something more complicated than just return a member, if you wanted:

```
void print_sin2x_all(const ThreeTypes arr[], int size)
{
    showArr(arr, size, [](const ThreeTypes& u) { return std::sin(2*u.real); });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In C++17 you should use `std::variant`:

```
using ThreeTypes = std::variant<char, int, double>;

template <std::size_t N>
auto show_arr(std::array<ThreeTypes, N>& arr)
{
    for (auto& e : arr)
    {
        std::visit([](auto e) { std::cout << e << std::endl;}, e);
    }
}

auto test()
{
    std::array<ThreeTypes, 2> arr = {3.4, 'a'};

    show_arr(arr);
}
```

Comment: std variant forces you to store the "which field is active" alongside the data.  The OP apparently has arrays of unions with *uniform* type active.  So there is some unavoidable inefficiency with variant here.

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont true. I still think we should go towards type safety with `std::variant`.

Comment: sure, but I think having a variant kinded view of a variant blob would be useful, where a variant is the result of merging the two into one type.  (the blob is the union, the kinded view is the value that says which part of the union is active). Splitting type information from storage can be really useful.  A lot of C++ features (needlessly?) tie them together, like how vtables are implemented.